# upload_to attribute seems not to be used while saving a FileField

Tags: django, media, filefield

I can't get my `FileField`'s url set to what I want.

My model is defined by

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to="reports", null=True, blank=True)
    # more stuff
```

and I create an instance using:

```
myModel = MyModel()
myModel.pdf_file = "some_file.pdf"
myModel.save()
```

`myModel.pdf_file.url` returns `<MEDIA_URL>/some_file.pdf`, while I would expect it to be `<MEDIA_URL>/reports/some_file.pdf`, because of the `upload_to` attribute.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I first tried to set a `File` object instead of a `string` but it duplicates my file with a `_<duplication_num>` appended to it, so I first create my file in a tmp folder, and delete it:

```
myModel.pdf_file = File(open(TMP_FILE_PATH + filename))
myModel.save()

# now that the file is saved to its final location, delete tmp

filepath = os.path.abspath(TMP_FILE_PATH + filename)
os.remove(filepath)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`upload_to` is used for uploading, You're assigning the string name directly. upload_to takes action only when you create a FileField object (by uploading from a form).

You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Answer (score 1):

`upload_to` is a directory relative to your project root where the **files** you upload are meant to be stored. But you are not assigning it a file, you are assigning it a string, which seems to be causing your `FileField` to assume you have a file named `some_file.pdf` in your `MEDIA_ROOT`.

*Repeat*: assigning a filename (string) makes `FileField` to ignore the path defined in `upload_to` and takes the given string as the real path.

Good luck :)